# Why the dataframe is altered when only df.to_numpy() is involved in the computation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, object, numpy-ndarray

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PawinData/UC/SFBA/DistanceMatrix_shortestnetworks.csv"
Distance_df = pd.read_csv(url, index_col=0)

D = Distance_df.to_numpy()
```

I have a dataframe `Distance_df` and I convert it to a numpy array `D` for computation. What happens subsequently only concerns `D` and doesn't involve `Distance_df` at all. However, both `D` and `Distance_df` are altered (to the same thing) in the end.

Although I can't figure out why `D` would change either, it's the behavior of `Distance_df`, the dataframe, that puzzles me the most. **How can it be altered when it doesn't even show up in the code?** Somehow I sense that this is not about the code but how values and objects are handled behind the scene. Can anybody explain a little bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `copy=True` as an argument to `to_numpy()`.

According to [`DataFrame.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) docs:

> copy : *bool, default False*
>
> Whether to ensure that the returned value is a not a view on another array. Note that `copy=False` does not *ensure* that `to_numpy()` is no-copy. Rather, `copy=True` ensure that a copy is made, even if not strictly necessary.

In other words, writing `D = Distance_df.to_numpy()` *may* result in `D` being a reference to the underlying numpy arrays of `Distance_df`, instead of copying them.

Write `D = Distance_df.to_numpy(copy=True)` to ensure that `D` and `Distance_df` are independent objects.

Comment: Very clarifying. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

try to get a copy of dataframe not to be altered

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PawinData/UC/SFBA/DistanceMatrix_shortestnetworks.csv"

Distance_df = pd.read_csv(url, index_col=0)

df=Distance_df.copy()

D = df.to_numpy()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
D = Distance_df.to_numpy()
```

Running now `D is Distance_df` returns `True`. Both variables refer to the same object.

However, if you do `D = Distance_df.copy().to_numpy()`, `D is Distance_df` will return `False`. They are now different objects.

It's just how Python handles variable references.

Comment: Thank you! I'm wary of variable references now.